# What is the only One open statement per connection limitation in JDBC-ODBC Bridge?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, concurrency, odbc, jdbc-odbc

Can someone explain/elaborate the following limitation mentioned on the [JDBC ODBC FAQs list](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-138427.html#15)

- -Does the JDBC-ODBC Bridge support multiple concurrent open statements per connection?
  No. **You can open only one Statement object per connection** when you are using the JDBC-ODBC Bridge.*

I tried opening multiple statements using JDBC/ODBC bridge drive, but did not get any issues.

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
//Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection conn =  DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:odbc:MyDSN", "user", "pwd");
Statement stmt1 = conn.createStatement ();
Statement stmt2 = conn.createStatement ();
ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery("select COL1 from TAB1");
ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery("select COL2 from TAB2");
if (rs1.next() )
//print COL1
if (rs2.next() )
//print COL2

//close all resources

-- DatabaseMetaData --
getDriverName() JDBC-ODBC Bridge (msorcl32.dll)
getJDBCMajorVersion() 2
getDriverVersion() 2.0001 (02.575.1132)
```

Comment: Why are you using the JDBC/ODBC bridge at all? Today all DBMS have very good "native" JDBC (Type4) drivers. There is nearly no reason to use the ODBC bridge (with all its bugs and limitations)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I mostly prefer Type4 drivers. I posted this question for clarification purpose.